# Como colocar um loop de colunas da DB dentro de um array?

Tags: php, mysql, array

Tenho um banco de dados com colunas dinâmicas que podem uma hora aparecer, outra hora não... também podem vir a ser adicionadas mais colunas ou mesmo extraídas as que já existem.

Eu fiz um código que me permite capturar estas colunas no meu banco de dados em tempo real e agora preciso fazer com que estas colunas apareçam em outra parte do código:

```
<?php

require("setup_do_banco.php");

$colunas    = $pdo->prepare("SHOW COLUMNS FROM imovel"); 
$colunas->execute();

###### Aqui tenho todos as colunas do meu banco de dados
while ( $coluna = $colunas->fetch() ) { 
    $coluna = $coluna["Field"]; echo "$coluna <br />"; 
}

$array = array (
    'key'       => '8b0dc65f996f98fd178a9defd0efa077',
    'module'    => 'imoveis',
    'method'    => 'busca_imoveis',
    'field'     => array (
    ////////////////////////////////
    #                   <------------
    ////////////////////////////////
    )   
);

$client = new SoapClient(null, array (
    'uri' => 'http://soap.imo.bi/',
    'location' =>
    'http://soap.imo.bi/soap.dll',
    'trace' => 'trace'
    )
);

$res = $client->get($array);

echo "<pre>"; print_r($res); echo "</pre>";

?>
```

Como podem ver, através de um loop eu recuperei todas as colunas do meu banco de dados e agora preciso plantá-las dentro do lugar que está a ***seta*** cada campo com vírgula no final e quebra de linha. Eu testei colocar o loop dentro do array mas não deu certo.

Como vou colocar as colunas do meu banco ali no lugar da flecha?

Comment: Porque não declarar essa array __antes__ do while, e no while pôr `$array['field'][] = $coluna["Field"];`

Comment: Não vou saber fazer isso, pode me ajudar?

Comment: Se esse array deve ter o conteúdo que está na tabela então [a resposta do bigown](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/45206/129)  é o que você precisa e é bem mais limpo.

Comment: Podem me ajudar na **Atualização** do que eu consegui fazer. Ele está atribuindo o retorno em `$array['field']` mas este está inserindo o número do índice. Preciso exatamente do código demonstrado em **Atualização**.

Comment: Marcos, tens estado a transformar a pergunta e a revelar problemas novos que não estavam na pergunta inicial. Assim as primeiras respostas perdem sentido e a pergunta fica uma salada. Por favor faz perguntas específicas para problemas específicos e se tiveres um novo problema que não consegues resolver sozinho faz uma nova pergunta. Como reparaste voltei atrás nas tuas atualizações da pergunta. Agora a resposta aceite fica meio descontextualizada...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Baseado na atualização e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/45259/91), a única mudanção é no lugar um índice numerico definir uma chave que é composta pela descrição do campo do banco que é representando por: `$item['field']`.

```
<?php
//O fetchAll() deve retornar um array nesse formato.
$array_banco = array(
                0 => array('field' =>  'DATA', 'description' => 'Data cadastro'),
                1 => array('field' => 'ENDERECO', 'description' => 'Endereço'),
                2 => array('field' => 'BAIRRO', 'description' => 'Bairro'));


$array = array (
    'key'       => '8b0dc65f996f98fd178a9defd0efa077',
    'module'    => 'imoveis',
    'method'    => 'busca_imoveis',
    'field'     => array() 
);


foreach($array_banco as $item){
    $array['field'][$item['field']] = sprintf("'%s' => '%s'", $item['field'], $item['description']);
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($array);


echo $array['field']['DATA'] .' - '. $array['field']['ENDERECO'] .' - '. $array['field']['BAIRRO'];
```

Saída:

```
Array
(
    [key] => 8b0dc65f996f98fd178a9defd0efa077
    [module] => imoveis
    [method] => busca_imoveis
    [field] => Array
        (
            [DATA] => 'DATA' => 'Data cadastro'
            [ENDERECO] => 'ENDERECO' => 'Endereço'
            [BAIRRO] => 'BAIRRO' => 'Bairro'
        )

)
'DATA' => 'Data cadastro' - 'ENDERECO' => 'Endereço' - 'BAIRRO' => 'Bairro'
```

Comment: Só uma observação. esta saída não vai rodar meu SOAP. Preciso que seja `'DATA' => 'Data cadastro'` ... Ah e eu não vou conseguir montar `$array_banco`. Obrigado pela sua ajuda.

Comment: @MarcosVinicius, alterei a resposta, `$array_banco` tem a mesma estruta de um array retornado por `fetchAll()`, fiz ele apenas para teste.

Comment: Estou quase chegando ao que eu preciso. Pode me dar mais uma força em **Atualização 2**?

Comment: Não entendi, no código da pergunta você está recriando `$array` depois do foreach

Answer (score 4):

Acho que precisas trocar a ordem das coisas para simplificar...

Sugestão:

```
require("setup_do_banco.php");

$array = array (
    'key'       => '8b0dc65f996f98fd178a9defd0efa077',
    'module'    => 'imoveis',
    'method'    => 'busca_imoveis',
    'field'     => array ()   
);

$colunas    = $pdo->prepare("SHOW COLUMNS FROM imovel"); 
$colunas->execute();

while ( $coluna = $colunas->fetch() ) { 
    $array['field'][] = $coluna["Field"];
}
```

Dessa maneira esse `$array['field']` vai ser preenchido **dentro** do while, e passado este código a array está "preenchida".

Comment: +1 Solução boa se o problema requerer extrair uma coluna em particular do `SHOW COLUMNS`.

Answer (score 4):

Não sei se entendi mas acho que seria só isto:

```
$array['field'] = $colunas->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Database/FetchAll.php).

O [`FetchAll`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) retorna justamente um *array* associativo completo cujas chaves são os nomes dos campos e os valores que foram retornados nele.

Comment: +1 Solução excelente se a ideia é passar o que vem do `SHOW COLUMNS` para a entrada no outro `array`: `$array['field'] = $colunas->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`.

Comment: @Zuul bem notado mexi lá.

Answer (score 2):

Simplesmente crie um array pegando os campos e depois faça com que o "field" receba esse *array*:

```
###### Aqui tenho todos as colunas do meu banco de dados
$fields = array();
while ( $coluna = $colunas->fetch() ) { 
    $fields[] = $coluna;
}

$array = array (
    'key'       => '8b0dc65f996f98fd178a9defd0efa077',
    'module'    => 'imoveis',
    'method'    => 'busca_imoveis',
    'field'     => $fields 
);
```

Ou como foi dito nos comentários apenas crie o *array* antes do *loop* e receba os dados direto no *array*:

```
$array = array (
    'key'       => '8b0dc65f996f98fd178a9defd0efa077',
    'module'    => 'imoveis',
    'method'    => 'busca_imoveis',
    'field'     => array() 
);

while ( $coluna = $colunas->fetch() ) { 
    $array ['field'][] = $coluna;
}
```

Comment: Pode me ajudar com esta pergunta que é semelhante mas diferente? Obrigado. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/45259/como-buscar-dados-do-banco-de-dados-e-coloc%C3%A1-los-num-array